# iOS 7 issue with UISearchBar

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchbar

Both SearchBar Delegate Methods and UITextFieldDelegate(Text Field which is inside UISearchBar) Methods are calling on second time (but not on first time).

This is working fine in iOS6.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

UISearchBarDelegate methods are working as expected on iOS 7. Also, by using them you have access to all functionalities; so there's no need to implement UITextFieldDelegate methods only for the textField inside the UISearchBar. You should provide more details about what you are trying to do.